# Is there way to edit and save the existing pdf stamp without changing the rest of the pdf

Tags: c#-4.0, itext, nunit, pdfsharp, approval-tests

Can somebody help me with a code rather than asking me to refer to itextsharp and pdf.

Basically I am trying to edit an existing pdf timestamp in the first page and a date in the second page, which is in a table and its a 100 page document. I am using C# approval test to compare the two pdf's. But is fails in these two instances of date place. So could somebody help me with C# code that will read the existing pdf, edit the pdf in the same place and save the same pdf.

Thanks

Comment: How far did you get in your own attempt to solve the issue? What was the tangible problem stopping you?

Comment: Your approval test is probably wrong. It probably assumes that a process that creates or manipulates a PDF always creates the same PDF when using the same code. For reasons that are inherent to the PDF specification, that isn't true.

Comment: Not an answer to how to change the pdf, but instead would suggest mocking out the dates so the pdf is generated with the dates you want.

Comment: Alternatively, ApprovalTests does scrub some date info already, you might be able to extend that:
https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net/blob/30446a86e011f015de228fb5e9857166c842bae6/ApprovalTests/Scrubber/PdfScrubber.cs